# Open a executable with "sh" under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working with the API for Sonar (http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/4.5/apidocs/org/sonar/api/utils/command/Command.html) and it says for the function to execute commands that "the command will be executed with sh executable."
What I want to to do is just use

> tslint path/to/my/code.ts

in the terminal (since this works). But the damn method excutes the line with "sh" so it looks something like this

> sh tslint path/to/my/code.ts

and gives me the error

> sh: 0: can't open tslint

How do I work around this to just execute "tslint" even though the command starts with sh?

Thanks for the help

EDIT: Since many of you asked what the java code looks like that produces this command (not mine, it's from an open source project):

```
Command command = Command.create("tslint");  
command.addArgument("--config " + configFile + " --format json " + file.trim());
```

final EDIT:
working version:

```
Command command = Command.create("node");  
        command.addArgument(pathToTsLint);  
        command.addArgument("--format");  
        command.addArgument("json");  
        command.addArgument("--config");  
        command.addArgument(configFile);  
        command.addArgument(file.trim());  
        command.setNewShell(false);
```

Comment: did you add the permission "excute " to that file ? check chmod command

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to use. In the shell, you could use `sh -c 'tslint path/to/my/code.ts'`, but it isn't clear how to adapt this to the API you are using.

Comment: `Command command = Command.create("tslint");`
`command.addArgument("--config " + configFile + " --format json " + file.trim());`

Comment: so what I want is the command `tslint --config /path/to/my/config.json --format json /path/to/my/code.ts` but because of the API it automatically inserts a "sh" at the start.

Comment: `sh -c 'tslint --version'` works and returns the version number but if I try the full command `sh -c 'tslint --config /home/vagrant/ASD-CDP/./.sonar/tslint.json
--format json /home/vagrant/ASD-CDP/cd-portal-ui/lib/ls2/utilities/modules-installer/module-installer.ts'` I get gibberish: http://i.imgur.com/ibAT9ku.png

Comment: `sh -c 'tslint /path/to/my/code.ts'` also works. if I add `--format json` it no longer works (same gibberish as above)

Comment: @ManuelHuber what you call gibberish is the correct output formated as json! If you use the `tslint` command within `Comand.create(...` you must use the full pathname of the `tslint` because there is no PATH environment variable in this context set.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. So now I can manually start it, using "sh" but apparently the damn API has other plans: http://i.imgur.com/PYFGmOd.png "Der Befehl lautet" is german for "this command is" wich is just a printf I added to see what the command looks like after command.addArgument. So apparently the shell/context the Sonar API is using doesn't allot "-c" ???

Comment: @ManuelHuber have a look at my newly edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the terminal with `which tslint` the full path of the file.
From the terminal you can all it with

`/bin/sh -c "/path/to/tslint /path/to/my/code.ts"`

With the Sonar API it is:

```
Command command = Comman.create('/full/path/name/to/tslint');
command.addArgument("--config " + configFile + " --format json " + file.trim());
```

You don't need the `-c` parameter from the `sh` command, but you must use the absolute path to the `tslint` command.

Comment: @ManuelHuber lock at the corrected version of my answer.

Comment: I tried that: http://i.imgur.com/TufhCsY.png and got a really strange error:http://i.imgur.com/vNgxF3m.png "word unexpected, expected ")"?! What Oo

Comment: @ManuelHuber Have you set `command.setNewShell(true)` for this command? If so, set it to `false`.

Comment: Hi! Yes, it was set to true and setting it to false was part of the solution. I looked at it and all that "setNewShell" did was add the "sh" to the string (on any OS other than windows). The final solution, that's running on our server right now is in my original post. Thanks for the help mate <3